# angular2-multiselect-dropdown compile issue

Tags: angular, tween.js

There was a problem after installation angular2-multiselect-dropdown

> ERROR in node_modules/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/lib/virtual-scroll/virtual-scroll.d.ts:2:24 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@tweenjs/tween.js'. 'D:/local/client/front-end-client/node_modules/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/node_modules/@tweenjs/tween.js/src/Tween.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

```
import * as tween from '@tweenjs/tween.js';
```

Already install @tweenjs/tween.js.

Comment: How did you import  module and what kind of version you use ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and nothing seems to solved it, but I uninstalled angular2-multiselect-dropdown (4.6.9) and I installed 4.2.3 and everything worked fine. Hope it helps somebody this.

npm uninstall  angular2-multiselect-dropdown
npm install  angular2-multiselect-dropdown@4.2.3

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for now.

1. `npm i @types/tween.js --save`
2. remove `"types": []` from `tsconfig.app.json`

It's working after that.

[Source PR](https://github.com/CuppaLabs/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/issues/482#issuecomment-629148438)

Hopefully, the developer might fix it soon.